# Magnific Popup - lightbox issue, plus mfp-hide seems to do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

This is my first time using stackoverflow so please be patient with me, heh.

I'm a relative newbie when it comes to HTML, CSS and JS, but I gotta use them for work every now and then. Today I've applied [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to a site I'm working on. I'm specifically trying to use the "Open with fade-zoom animation" example, and modify it to fit my needs of course. The popup is working, indeed, but the div for the popup box itself isn't hiding, despite having mfp-hide as its class. It's weird because the Dreamweaver preview does hide it, but Chrome does not (I'm on latest version of Chrome for Windows, if it helps.) Also, the lightbox that the Magnific Popup site displays behind every popup is nowhere to be seen.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hkuwdr7/) with my code. The posting interface says I need to post my code here so here it goes:

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#dialog">
        <span>CLICK HERE TO DISPLAY DIALOG</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
    <h1>DIALOG TITLE</h1>
    <br><br>
    <p>Dialog text</p>
</div>
```

My JS (located inside a `script` block right before my `</body>` tag)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        fixedContentPos: false,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
});
```

And just in case, my CSS (located inside a `style` block right over the `script` block with the JS)

```
/* Styles for dialog window */
#dialog {
background: white;
padding: 20px 30px;
text-align: left;
max-width: 700px;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
z-index: 999;
top: 100px
}

/**
* Fade-zoom animation
*/

/* start state */
.my-mfp-zoom-in .zoom-anim-dialog {
display:block;
opacity: 0;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 

-webkit-transform: scale(0.8); 
-moz-transform: scale(0.8); 
-ms-transform: scale(0.8); 
-o-transform: scale(0.8); 
transform: scale(0.8); 
}

/* animate in */
.my-mfp-zoom-in.mfp-ready .zoom-anim-dialog {
opacity: 1;

-webkit-transform: scale(1); 
-moz-transform: scale(1); 
-ms-transform: scale(1); 
-o-transform: scale(1); 
transform: scale(1); 
}

/* animate out */
.my-mfp-zoom-in.mfp-removing .zoom-anim-dialog {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.8); 
-moz-transform: scale(0.8); 
-ms-transform: scale(0.8); 
-o-transform: scale(0.8); 
transform: scale(0.8); 

opacity: 0;
}

/* Dark overlay, start state */
.my-mfp-zoom-in.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
-moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
-o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
/* animate in */
.my-mfp-zoom-in.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0.8;
}
/* animate out */
.my-mfp-zoom-in.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0;
}
```

That's all I've got. I'm sorry if this question's been answered already, I have not been able to find it. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help solve the problem. And thanks in advance for reading. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where the mfp-hide class did nothing. It was caused by not properly including Magnific Popup's css. Check to see if this is your root cause too. You can include the following:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.1/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```